# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hope you're well.
I'm trying to make it so when a countdown reaches zero, 10 is added to a float, currentNeed but we call it seedNeed in this script. Anyway, this doesn't work, and this error is displayed on the console: "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement."

Here's the code:

```
public float timeLeft = 10f;
public SeedNeed seedNeed;
public void Update()
{
    timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;

    if (timeLeft <= 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("IM READY TO HARVEST");
        Destroy(gameObject);
        seedNeed.currentNeed + 10;


        
   }

}
```

}

And the line that the error is on is `seedNeed.currentNeed + 10;`

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to increment `seedNeed.currentNeed` by 10? If so, you need to use the `+=` operator.

Answer (score 1):

The last line of your code

```
seedNeed.currentNeed + 10;
```

it's not a statement but an expression.
If you want to add 10 to seedNeed.currentNeed's current value, your code should be:

```
seedNeed.currentNeed += 10;
```

Further reading: [+ and += operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-operator)

Comment: Blasuttio thank for the reply, I tried it and while the error is now gone, the 10 isn't being added. Thanks though!

Comment: Since _currentNeed_ is a property of the class _SeedNeed_, there may be some business logic in the property setter. Do you have access to _SeedNeed_ source? If so, check if the declaration is just something like `public int currentNeed { get; set; }` or something more complex.

Comment: Blasutto thanks for the response, just tried it with this code: get {return currentNeed} set { currentNeed = value}      that's what the tutorial I just watched showed me. However this still is not working, I'm still getting the same error which is odd